# Java Guessing number game

Tags: java

I'm rookie with JAVA and I've been trying to writing code for number guessing game which the computer pick the number from 0 - 500
condition:
If the number is too low the user enter 0 and the computer guess lower number
If the number is too high the user enter 1 and the computer guess higher number

And ends game with 5 guess

here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Guessinggame1000 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            double r = Math.random() * 500 + 1;
            int x = (int) r;
            int n = in.nextInt();
            double high = x;
            double low = x ;
            if (n == 0) high = (int) (Math.random()) * 500 + x;
            System.out.println(((int) high));
            if (n == 1) low = (int) (Math.random()) * x;
            System.out.println(((int) low));
            if (i == 5) System.out.println("We've lost");

        }
    }
}
```

It seems like when I ran the solution , I cannot get the computer to print higher or lower number but just the random numbers.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated !!! :D

Comment: This is a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  As you use a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes and observe, one line at a time, the exact values of your variables and how each individual operation modifies those values.  When you do this, on which line of your code do you first observe an unexpected result?  What were the inputs to that line of code?  What was the result?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: You should use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1)` instead. Or if you're on Java < 1.7 `Random.nextInt`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it sounds like a bad idea to use `double`s. Use `int`s instead, and a `Random` object that has useful methods:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int r = random.nextInt(500)+1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(r);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        if (n == 0) {
            r = random.nextInt(500-r)+r+1;
        } else if (n == 1) {
            r = random.nextInt(r-1)+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: To avoid mistakes with improper use of `Random` I would advise to use `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` instead.

Comment: @Neijwiert I disagree.

Answer (score 1):

i tried to make it cleaner and more readable for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // cleaner and easier way to produce random Int Numbers
        //because there will be no need to cast numbers anymore
        Random ran = new Random();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int range = ran.nextInt(501) ;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            int n = in.nextInt();

            if (n == 0)
                range = ran.nextInt(501 - range);
            System.out.println(range);
            if (n == 1)
                range = ran.nextInt(range);
            System.out.println(range);
            if (i == 5)
                System.out.println("We've lost");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `(int) (Math.random()) * 500 + x` since you are casting `Math.random()` to an integer it is always 0. Try `(int) (Math.random() * 500) + x` (note the brace changes)

**EDIT**

Also I know this is not the full answer to your question, but since you mentioned that you are getting familiar with Java now, i don't want to help too much (that kills the joy i think)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i know there are better solutions for this problem, but he is a beginner i don't want to give him the full answer. I hope you unterstand it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an MCVE so you can see how to solve this problem. Don't just copy it but instead read it, understand it, and play around with it to experiment. If you're confused about anything then feel free to ask.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int GUESSES = 5;
    final int RANGE = 100;
    final char GUESS_LOWER_KEY = '1';
    final char GUESS_HIGHER_KEY = '2';

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    // max possible guess and min possible guess
    // they will be adjusted when you say 'higher' or 'lower'
    int max = RANGE;
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < GUESSES; i++) {
        // get a random number between the min and max
        // rand.nextInt(n) gets a number between 0 and n - 1
        // Examples:
        // nextInt(50 - 0 + 1) + 0 -> nextInt(51) + 0 -> rand from 0 to 50
        // nextInt(33 - 24 + 1) + 24 -> nextInt(10) + 24 -> rand from 24 to 33
        int guess = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        System.out.println("I guess: " + guess);

        char n = in.next().charAt(0);
        if (n == GUESS_LOWER_KEY)
            max = guess - 1; // guess - 1 to keep max inclusive
        if (n == GUESS_HIGHER_KEY)
            min = guess + 1; // guess + 1 to keep min inclusive

        System.out.println("min = " + min + "; max = " + max);
        if (max < min) {
            System.out.println("You lie, the answer has to be " + guess);
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("I've lost!");
}
```